# How to return query in key value like formate, how to add multiple queries to return Response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-orm, django-serializer

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    production_house = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    year = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) # When it was create
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) # When i was update
    creator = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='movies', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class ProductionHouse(models.Model):
    p_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    p_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

i am working on an existing project, all the tables are flat, no foreign key. i have to return query from two tables. see the models, i need to return ProductionHouse as key and all the movies that are prouduced by this ProductionHouse will be value. for more clarity

"ProductionHouse1":{
"title":"title1"
"genere":"genere1"
all the fields
},
{
"title":"title2"
"genre":"genere3"
all the fields
}

"ProductionHouse2":{
"title":"title1"
"genre":"genere1"
all the fields
},

or simple
"productionHouse1":{
movies queryset1
movies queryset2
movies queryset3 ...
},
"productionHouse2":{

movies queryset1 ...
},
and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MovieProductionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    movies= MovieSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model= ProductionHouse
        fields=['id','title','production_house', 
              'created_at','updated_at','year', 'creater','movies'
               ]
```